# Disable Focus behavior on nav links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, onfocus

Pretty much my problem minus the buttons - my issue applies to anchor links: [How to stop buttons from staying depressed with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443579/how-to-stop-buttons-from-staying-depressed-with-bootstrap-3)

I am using Bootstrap 3 (testing in FF & Chrome), and my .navbar is fixed with a scrollspy function. When I click on a nav link, the link stays in *Focused* mode (and while scrolling without clicking outside - my nav now shows both links! [1 active/1focus]), and the only way to remove the focus state is to click anywhere outside the nav. Focus state is not a visible issue in Safari.

**How would I go about UNfocusing the nav link automatically with mousedown/mouseup instead?**

**EDIT:** Mouseup/mousedown was not the underlying issue as previously thought.

My #nav in case anyone is wondering. Thanks!

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

   <nav role="navigation" id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">TOP</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
                    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#work">WORK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Why not use the mouseup event and remove the class that causes the focus from all the navbar elements?

Comment: Turns out the focus issue was in the CSS styles and that's why the mouseup events were not working.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Particular detail that resolved my dilemma. Now works in FF and Chrome.

The (scrollspy) active link that needed to be styled

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {color: #262A3A;}
```

and removed `.navbar .nav > li > a:focus {color: red;}` that lingered underneath on mousedown.

Answer (score 2):

jquery solution, since you asked for mousedown/mouseup:

```
$(".navbar-brand").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).blur();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/re2hLe8r/

Comment: Unfortunately, this and many variations of it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want only to use the .active  css class for showing the selected nav. 
One option would be to override the bootstrap's default color on focused nav's.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color:#777;
    outline:none; // to remove possible blue borders
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sygn/3k7e88p9/

Comment: I have tried to change colors before but the focus behavior is still stuck regardless of color.

Comment: @Jenn can you provide a code example where your problem is shown?

Comment: The jsfiddle example I made can't seem to recognize the links as focused when I code it. Here is an alternative template that also showcased my problem: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/

It is really subtle, but when you click on any nav link THEN scroll (don't click anywhere else), that focus link will be a darker color than the remaining links until you click elsewhere on the page. 

You are correct in terms of styling the focus navs - I will edit above what did work. Thanks!

Comment: @Jenn Maybe it gets overriden, try adding the !important keyword
 color:#777!important;