# Permanently disable focus from navigation links

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

my problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886441/disable-focus-behavior-on-nav-links). I want to disable focus feature from links in navigation bar.
The links:

```
<ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 active">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2">Second</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've added the `outline` style that is supposed to turn off that feature:

```
<style>
  .nav-link {
    color: #888888;
  }
  .nav-link:hover {
    color: black;
  }
  .nav-link:focus {
    outline:none;
  }
  .active {
    color: black;
  }
</style>
```

But it's still working in unwanted way:
[image] (the blue effect)

I do not want to set color of it since in my case any (black or 888888) wouldn't be correct, just want to disable this behaviour.
For sure it is `.nav-link:focus` because changing `outline:none;` to `color:red;` blue focus changes to red one.

What I have tried:

```
outline: none;
outline: 0;
outline: 0 !important;
outline: 0 none !important;
```

and similar.

The whole header code (after setting `color: initial` and `outline: thin dotted;`) :

```css
.nav-link {
  color: #898989;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  color: black;
}
.nav-link:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: initial !important;
}

.active {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="p-3 text-bg-light">
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">

    <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 active">First</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2">Second</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Be sure you're not removing important usability features out of vanity. See https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/.

Comment: @isherwood So what should I do instead? I really not like this blue thing, and setting it to black/gray can be confused with currect active element.

Comment: Yes, it seems that .nav-link {outline: thin dotted;} is really nice. However I still need to disable color-changing feature and an article doesn't help with that.

Comment: Yes, they are, and nothing connected with color-changing behovior. In fact it listed me what I set.

Comment: active is not giving me the problem, only focus (force focus). However in both cases: nothing unusual.

Comment: updated (added `color: initial` and `outline: thin dotted;`). I don't want to change color to black when dots appear (dots should stay).

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz this will truly hurt accessibility

Comment: First: It won't (there are dots for that). Second: even if, I do want to know how to do it.

Comment: Fixed - it changed behavior slightly - it seems `.nav-link color: #898989` is not considered then, however the issue is still the same. After clicking text is changing to black and I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe setting the color to initial on your focus state should solve the issue:

```
.nav-link:focus {
    color: initial
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51748038/20913924) on a previous question shows more of what you can do to reset the default browser styles for the anchor element.

Comment: It changes color to black in my case.

Comment: Updated the demo with `color: initial`

Comment: What color do you want it to be? just set it to that

Comment: I want it to not to change. One is black, one is gray. After hit I want to not change. I can't assign the color since then (for example "I want black") it will change to black also for gray text.

Comment: Additionally I don't care what the color is and there may be a situation that I don't know the "initial color". I just want "keep the color and don't change it" functionality.