# Bootstrap 4 - button that opens modal remains highlighted/clicked after modal close

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm using the button below to open a modal

but after I close the modal it appears to remain highlighted/clicked with a shadow. I thought I would simply be able to correct this using a modal event handler...

```js
$('#MyModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
  $(".btn-secondary").blur();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="text-center mb-2">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm custom" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal"> 
Button
</button></div>
```

The blur function works on a test button that doesn't open the modal but has no impact on the buttons that do open the modal. How can I get the buttons **(.btn-secondary)** to no longer appear highlighted/clicked???

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following style:

```
.btn-secondary:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Be aware that this will apply to all buttons with class `.btn-secondary` (which is obviously a bootstrap class). If you want to apply the style to a specific button only, use a unique class or id.

Comment: Thanks @Pieter for feedback. It gets rid of shadow but buttons still appear clicked - they are the hover color. Right now I'm going with `shadow-none` which has the same affect as your css solution. I'm using a bootswatch theme so I guess there's no way around it unless I go back to plain bootstrap, but still doesn't make sense why blur works for other buttons???

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the solution I [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443579/how-to-stop-buttons-from-staying-depressed-with-bootstrap-3) which makes uses of anchor rather than button... it's several years old but the best for my situation

```
<div class="text-center mb-2"><a role="button" style="color:white" 
class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm custom"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal"</a></div>-->
```